# How to compute the total number of bills per clients'age?

Tags: pyspark

I have two datasets, one the client with their respective bills,with the following elements: "number of bill", "date", "client", import", and the other dataset are the clients grouped by age.

****An example:****

```
1st Dataset             
u'F1,01/01/2013,C1,11'

2nd Dataset 
u'C1,20'
```

I have parsed the two data set to select the data of importance to my subject. Here is the code

```
def parseClients(clients):
    fields=clients.split(",")
    return (fields[0], fields[1])

def parseBill(bill):
    fields=bill.split(",")
    return (fields[2], bill)

new_bills=bills.map(parseBill)
new_clients=clients.map(parseClients)

Age_Bills=new_bills.join(new_clients)
```

A sample as following:

```
Age_Bills.take(10):
(u'C856', (u'F2982,06/01/2013,C856,88', u'81'))
(u'C856', (u'F11953,22/01/2013,C856,87', u'81'))
(u'C856', (u'F12893,24/01/2013,C856,10', u'81'))
(u'C856', (u'F12913,24/01/2013,C856,41', u'81'))
(u'C856', (u'F17883,02/02/2013,C856,45', u'81'))
(u'C856', (u'F17895,02/02/2013,C856,75', u'81'))
(u'C856', (u'F18867,04/02/2013,C856,105', u'81'))
(u'C856', (u'F21864,09/02/2013,C856,26', u'81'))
(u'C856', (u'F30889,26/02/2013,C856,154', u'81'))
(u'C856', (u'F49990,02/04/2013,C856,90', u'81'))
```

Now I'd like to count the number of bills
 per age, but I don't know how to continue. I have thought about using KeyReduce or flatmap. I would  be grateful if you could help me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
Age_Bills.map(lambda x: (x[1][1], 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
```